# Django 1.8 migration did not take affect

Tags: sqlite, django-1.8

Using Django 1.8 with a SQLite database.
I made a change in models.py that consisted of eliminating two out of four elements from a field choice and editing one of the remaining two:

Original value:

```
OPTION_INSPECTOR = (
    ('John Smith', 'John Smith'),
    ('Taylor', 'Taylor'),
    ('Hale', 'Hale'),
    ('James', 'James'),
)
```

New value:

```
OPTION_INSPECTOR = (
    ('John Smith', 'John Smith'),
    ('Greg Taylor', 'Greg Taylor'),
)
```

I then ran:

`python manage.py makemigrations my_app`

I saw nothing unusual, only the changes that I made, if I recall correctly.  I do not have the actual output.

Then I ran:

```
python manage.py migrate my_app
```

Again, I don't remember anything unusual.  But, the model hasn't changed the choices within the dropdown menu on the Admin site.  Can anyone suggest a way to make this change successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am continually changing my app based on feedback from researchers. I have had a lot of issues like what you are describing. I have found that there are a lot of changes I can make to the models before the app total breaks and I have to go back and "remake" it with a fresh model.py file, but eventually, that is what I have had to do. In the meantime (before I remake the app), I make the changes to the model.py, then I run the makemigrations and then migrate. I look and see what the errors are and I make the changes to fix them directly in the database (in my case, MySQL). Typically, I have to do this to add or alter fields. Then, I rerun the make migrations and the migrate, and I get warnings about duplicate fields, but the app keeps working. Like I said though, eventually, I have to remake the app with a fresh model.py file to get rid of all the warnings.